# Subquery executes more than one row and my query is different

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT enquiry.*,
      (SELECT comm
       from comments
       where enquiry.id = comments.enquiryId
       order by time DESC
      ) as comm
FROM enquiry
where id='110' AND cmpId='3'
```

when i want to execute more than one row by removing limit it say "subquery executes more than one row"
Please help

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: Is it complaining that the sub query is returning more than one row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subquery is called a scalar subquery, meaning that it must have one column and at most one row.  One simple method is to put the results in multiple rows, using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT e.*, c.comments
FROM enquiry e JOIN
     comments c
     ON e.id = c.enquiryId
where e.id = 110 AND e.cmpId = 3;
```

Comment: Now i want to display more than one  row in select option tag

Comment: If this answer has solved the question you wrote please mark this as the best answer so the user can get the reputation for it

Answer (score 0):

Or you can put the subquery in the from clause (as below), which is similar to join condition.

```
SELECT enquiry.*, comm.comm
FROM enquiry,
      (SELECT comm
       from comments
       where enquiry.id = comments.enquiryId
       order by time DESC
      ) as comm
where id='110' AND cmpId='3'
```

Answer (score 0):

As the relation between enquiry & comments is 1 to many (as appears)
You need to add GROUP_CONCAT() functions to group all comments as follows:

```
SELECT enquiry.*,
      (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(comm)
       from comments
       where enquiry.id = comments.enquiryId
       order by time DESC
      ) as comm
FROM enquiry
where id='110' AND cmpId='3'
```